# What is a form based application?

Tags: forms, jsf, web-applications

What does it mean that an application is "form based"? I am reading the JSF specification and term turned up.

Comment: are you referring to Form-Based authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Form based application, means that for each form, there is a backend bean (java class) that handles the calls to the class.
For instance, you will have a form for login (login.xhtml) and you will present all getter and setters of the values that are needed in the form, in LoginBean.java

All operations (like retrieving data from db) **only** for this form, will be done in a `postconstruct` method.

So if login has username and password like this:

```
<h:inputtext name="name" value="#{loginBean.name}" />

<h:inputtext name="password" value="#{loginBean.password}" />
```

The LoginBean.java will look:

```
public class LoginBean{
    String name;
    String password;

    public getName(){return name;}
    public getPassword(){return password;}

    public setName(String name){
       this.name = name;
}
   public setPassword(String password){
       this.password = password;
}
   @PostContruct
   public void init(){
      this.name = ... //get the name from db
   }
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more?